# Proving that $f(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{ixy}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ixy}f(x)dxdy$.

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, functional-equations

I need to show that if $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ then $$\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{ixy}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ixy}f(x)dx\right)dy$$

Comment: This is simply the [Fourier Inversion Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_inversion_theorem#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20Fourier%20inversion,reconstruct%20the%20original%20wave%20precisely.)

Comment: @MarkViola 
I know that the expression inside the parentheses is the inverse of the Fourier transform and so it is sensible that the expression on the right is equal to f (x) that would be by the definition of inverse. In all books and places they only give the definition of the inverse but never the calculation of why it is they do it, that is why I would like to know the calculation of the expression that I wrote before to see the calculations until obtaining that the integrals on the right are f (X )

Answer (score 4):

The standard proof uses the idea of gaussian regularization. First, write

$$ \mathcal{F}\{f\}(\xi) = \hat{f}(\xi) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)e^{-i\xi x} \, \mathrm{d}x. $$

Since $\mathcal{F}$ is a continuous linear operator on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, it suffices to establish the Fourier inversion formula on a dense subset  $\mathcal{D}$ of $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$. For the purpose of  our proof, we will choose $\mathcal{D}$ such that $f \in C_b(\mathbb{R}) \cap L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\hat{f} \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ for each $f \in \mathcal{D}$. (Note that such $\mathcal{D}$ indeed exists. For instance, we may choose $\mathcal{D}$ as the [Schwartz space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space).)

Let $f \in \mathcal{D}$. Since $\hat{f} \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, the dominated convergence theorem tells that

$$ \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ix\xi} e^{-\epsilon \xi^2} \hat{f}(\xi) \, \mathrm{d}\xi = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ix\xi} \hat{f}(\xi) \, \mathrm{d}\xi. $$

On the other hand, by the Fubini's Theorem and the gaussian integral,

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ix\xi} e^{-\epsilon \xi^2} \hat{f}(\xi) \, \mathrm{d}\xi
&= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ix\xi} e^{-\epsilon \xi^2} \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-i\xi y}f(y) \, \mathrm{d}y \right) \, \mathrm{d}\xi \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i(x-y)\xi} e^{-\epsilon \xi^2} \, \mathrm{d}\xi \right) f(y) \, \mathrm{d}y \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\epsilon\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{(y-x)^2}{4\epsilon}} f(y) \, \mathrm{d}y
\end{align*}

Substituting $y=x+\sqrt{4 \epsilon \pi} \, t$, it follows that

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ix\xi} e^{-\epsilon \xi^2} \hat{f}(\xi) \, \mathrm{d}\xi
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\pi t^2} f(x+\sqrt{4 \epsilon \pi} \, t) \, \mathrm{d}t
\end{align*}

Since $f$ is bounded and continuous, this converges to

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\pi t^2} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}t = f(x) $$

as $\epsilon \to 0^+$ by the dominated convergence theorem. This proves that

$$ \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ix\xi} \hat{f}(\xi) \, \mathrm{d}\xi = f(x) $$

for all $f \in \mathcal{D}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$, hence establishing the Fourier inversion formula over $\mathcal{D}$. Now as mentioned in the beginning, this extends to all of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ via the continuity of $\mathcal{F}$.